# Unity error when installing post processing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I cant get post procesing to install. I get a bunch of error. [Here are some](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hcq8.png)

I have tried to reinstall unity a bunch of times in different versions but its not helping.

I installed from package manager

Comment: Have you imported the package from github, or tried to import directly from Package Manager ?

Comment: _"Unity error when installing post proccesing"_ - OP and up-voter perhaps need a refresher of [ask].

Comment: When posting a question be sure that your question's title _is a brief explanation of the issue you are having_ rather than _"Unity error when installing post proccesing"_ which isn't particulary helpful. What error? What kind of post processing?  Posts on SO are not just for the _"now"_ but also for readers in the future who, by using search engines come to SO seeking answers to problems that were solved years before.  For this reason it's important that the question's title take on a form that will correlate with search terms.  I don't think your title helps anyone today or the future.

Comment: I installed from package manager

Comment: As @MickyD said, you'll have to edit your question accordingly to the SO terms. By the way, have you tried to navigate to Library/PackageCache and delete the folder named "com.unity.postprocessing", so it can be downloaded again ?